# Convert image pixels to cartesian coordinates?

Tags: python

I'm working with MNIST and want to convert the image pixel values into an (x,y) coordinate system. I want it to work directly using a dataset where the image has shape (28,28).

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by "convert the image into a coordinate system".  If you have a 28x28 image, then the coordinates run from 0 to 27 in both directions.

Comment: Right, so how do I plot that on (x,y) coordinates?

Comment: Your question says NOTHING about plotting.  What, exactly, are you trying to get?  You can display those as images right away.  Do you just want to print out the 28x28 pixel values?

Comment: I want to take a single image, transform the values so we can make a copy of it using dots in the xy-plane

Comment: @TimRoberts  check out this link, just this first part https://towardsdatascience.com/revisiting-mnist-with-fresh-eyes-36f9d19a75d1

Comment: For gosh sakes, all they're doing is flipping the image over vertically.  Images traditionally have (0,0) in upper left, but graphs in algebra have (0,0) at lower left.  Worry about that detail later and get on with your analysis.

Comment: Im just asking for the code. Any other comment is unnecessary. If you do not understand my question, you should be able to understand from the link I sent. @TimRoberts

Comment: @TimRoberts Actually if you've actually read up on ML literature, it DOES care about the orientation of the image, and shifting it is indeed a valid technique for data augmentation. That's not even the point. I literally just need to code the conversion of image pixels to formulate into cartesian coordinates on a separate plot as done in the article. It's really not that hard of a question to understand. If you can't be of help then I suggest you put your time elsewhere.

Comment: The point is (a) your question (and the article) are unclear, and (b) you have put zero effort into the solution.  Both of those disqualify this as a StackOverflow question.  The phrase "convert an image to Cartesian coordinates" makes no sense.  If you had said "I want the X,Y coordinates of the non-zero pixels in this image," that is a problem that can be solved with basically one line of numpy code, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basis of what you're asking.  I open an image.  This one happens to be a 320x320 RGB image, so I extract the red plane.  The expression `img < 255` returns an  array the same size as `img` that contains True or False, depending on whether the element matches the condition.  `np.argwhere` then returns an Nx2 list of the coordinates of all of the True values.

The `[H-1]-i1[:1]` then inverts the Y coordinates of all of those points by subtracting from the maximum Y.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('abc.png')
img = np.array(img)[:,:,0]
print(img.shape)
i1 = np.argwhere(img < 255)
print(i1)
H = i1.shape[1]
i1[:1] = [H-1]-i1[:1]
print(i1)
```

Output:

```
(320, 320)
[[100 110]
 [100 111]
 [100 112]
 ...
 [250 258]
 [250 259]
 [250 260]]
(320, 320)
[[100 110]
 [100 111]
 [100 112]
 ...
 [250 258]
 [250 259]
 [250 260]]
[[100 209]
 [100 208]
 [100 207]
 ...
 [250  61]
 [250  60]
 [250  59]]
```